# making drag and drop upload with less javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I'm trying to make an upload holder for my website, so users can easily drag and drop a file on it.

there is a lot of libraries and events for doing that, but I need a simple way.

this ([thought](http://jsfiddle.net/skcQG/)) came to my mind...

I put a `file input` to the page and sets `width` and `height`.

now when my user drag a file on it, `onchange` event will work.

but I want to hide browse button and there is two way:

set `0 opacity`.(it is not working in some browsers)

set `hidden visibility`.(the thought is not working)

help me, what else I can try?

Comment: I would suggest shadow DOM, but that's hardly a working draft.

Answer (score 1):

Put the form on a hidden iframe. Use an ordinary div for the target. When the file is dropped, catch the event and update the input, then submit as post. The result is ajax-like uploading via file drag and drop.

Comment: Or you can use the `FileReader` to read the file when dropped and upload it with the new `XMLHTTPRequest` level 2 standard.